# Get all Sheet Names of open workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I have the below macro which lists all the worksheet names in the current(host) workbook.

I would like to adapt this code so it targets an active/open workbook, which has its workbook name & extension referenced in cell C1.

`range("C1").value`

Please can someone let me know how I adapt the below code.

```
Sub ListSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    
    x = 1
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is cell C1 in the workbook running the code (ThisWorkbook) or in the target workbook (ActiveWorkbook or another)? - note you've confused @Harun24HR. Is it in the ActiveSheet or a specific sheet? - note that Range("C1") refers to ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1"). Where do you want to write the names? - note that Sheets("Sheet1") refers to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ListSheets()
Dim inputwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, source As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long

' Change source sheet if it is NOT always the active worksheet
' or activate the source sheet first with Workbooks("NAME").Sheets(INDEX).Activate (not preferable)
Set source = ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
Set inputwb = Workbooks(Cells(1, 1).Value)
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not find workbook " & Cells(1, 1).Value & ". Subroutine execution stopped."
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
LRow = 1

For Each ws In inputwb.Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LRow, 1) = ws.Name
    LRow = LRow + 1
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, the output of the initial code is correct, however I want to get the sheet names of the workbook referenced in Cell C1 of ThisWorkBook.

Comment: I'll amend my post!

Comment: Would love the reason for the downvote... Very constructive criticism!

Comment: Since you ask, this A is not useful because: 1) use of implicit  ActiveSheet.  You don't know that the required Workbook/ Worksheet will be active when the code is run. 2) Unnecessary use of End - should be Exit Sub

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've considered both your points when I wrote my post. For point one, OP states "so it targets an active workbook", and this is reflected in their code too. End was used on purpose in the case that this is a nested subroutine.

Comment: The OP says _so it targets an active/open workbook, which has its workbook name & extension referenced in cell C1._  They don't say that that cell is in the Open/Active book, nor do they say which sheet is active.  When asked for clarity on that point they did not respond.  That uncertainty is likely part of the problem  the OP is trying to solve.  As to End, I see no nesting here.  Even if there was, the nuclear option is not necessary and is never a good idea. I stand by my criticisms, and my vote

Comment: FWIW, [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement)  _The End statement stops code execution abruptly, without invoking the Unload, QueryUnload, or Terminate event, or any other Visual Basic code. Code you have placed in the Unload, QueryUnload, and Terminate events of forms and class modules is not executed. Objects created from class modules are destroyed, files opened by using the Open statement are closed, and memory used by your program is freed. Object references held by other programs are invalidated._

Comment: @chrisneilsen I will amend my post. I appreciate the feedback, which is a lot better than simply a downvote

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job but you don't need the extension of the workbook just the  name.

```
Sub ListSheets()
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wbkName As String

    x = 1
    wbkName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value
           
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
    Set wbk = Application.Workbooks(wbkName)
           
    For Each ws In wbk.Worksheets
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    Next ws
        
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW, you _might_ need the extension.  Including it never does any harm.  But if you have set File Explorer to display extensions (yes, File Explorer, nothing in Excel itself) then including the extension is mandatory.